# Page route CodeIgniter I

Tags: codeigniter

I am using a reference book called PHP and MVC with CodeIgniter, and I’m following the examples of projects putting in my personal pc.It runs fine at my local PC and but gives some error at webserver. Diagnosis: The problem in question is the routes of pages. in my personal pc works normally, but when I put it on the web server can not find the requested page.

```
http://orion.locadados.com.br/~wladi/Carrinho_Compras/
http://orion.locadados.com.br/~wladi/Carrinho_Compras/categoria/artigos-esportivos
```

The routes defined in my project are as default for any server, because they are in the project folder itself. Just do not put the line of code, it would not know which part of the code put online.

How can i fix this?

file .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

the file routes.php

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| URI ROUTING
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| This file lets you re-map URI requests to specific controller functions.
|
| Typically there is a one-to-one relationship between a URL string
| and its corresponding controller class/method. The segments in a
| URL normally follow this pattern:
|
|   example.com/class/method/id/
|
| In some instances, however, you may want to remap this relationship
| so that a different class/function is called than the one
| corresponding to the URL.
|
| Please see the user guide for complete details:
|
|   http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html
|
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| RESERVED ROUTES
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| There area two reserved routes:
|
|   $route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
|
| This route indicates which controller class should be loaded if the
| URI contains no data. In the above example, the "welcome" class
| would be loaded.
|
|   $route['404_override'] = 'errors/page_missing';
|
| This route will tell the Router what URI segments to use if those provided
| in the URL cannot be matched to a valid route.
|
*/


$route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['categoria/(:any)'] = "home/categoria/$1";
$route['produto/(:any)'] = "produtos/detalhes_produto/$1";

$route['404_override'] = '';

/* End of file routes.php */
/* Location: ./application/config/routes.php */
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^sys.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^app.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
   ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

assuming that your system folder is **sys** and application folder is **app**

Comment: Is this the way of changing the htaccess file? Http://suporte.netpoint.com.br/habilitar-mod-rewrite-no-cpanel/

Answer (score 0):

For me this htaccess works with the latest CI version

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Try with this